# 'Classical' proof of Main Theorem of elimination theory by Mumford

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, quantifier-elimination

I despair on a argument in the in proof of the
Main Theorem of elimination theory (pges 33-35) in Mumford's  Algebraic Geometry I: Complex
Algebraic Varieties. The MToet states that the projection
$p_2: \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m \to \mathbb{P}^m$ is
closed, i.e., if $Z \subset \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m$ is a
closed algebraic set, then so is $p_2(Z)$.

Mumford gives two proofs, the modern one using Nullstellensatz and
a classical approach based on resultants. A step in the second one
(pges 34-35) I not understand. Mumford makes some reduction steps and your job is finally to show that if $S \subset \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{C}^m$ is closed, then
$p_2(S)$ is closed too.

Assume $S$ is defined by $f_i(Z_1,...,Z_m, X,Y)=0, 1 \le i \le l$
where $f_i \in \mathbb{C}[Z_1,...,Z_m, X,Y]$ are homogeneneous in
$X$ and $Y$ of degree $d$, $Z_i$ coordinates on $\mathbb{C}^m$. Look at the *resultant* of the two polynomials in $X, Y$:

$$R(\sum t_i f_i(Z; X, Y), \sum s_i f_i(Z; X,Y))$$

and expand it as polynomial in $t_i$ and $s_i$:

$$R= \sum R_{\alpha \beta}(Z) t^{\alpha} s^{\beta}$$

Mumford claims that the equations $R_{\alpha \beta}(Z)=0$ for all
$\alpha, \beta$ define in image $p_2(S)$.

In general if $k$ is a closed field (here $k= \mathbb{C}$) and
$f(X,Y)= \sum a_i X^{n-i} Y^i, g(X,Y)= \sum b_j X^{n-j} Y^j $
are *homogeneneous* polynomials then the *resultant*

$$R(f,g):= R(a_,...,a_n; b_,...,b_m)$$

has the property to be zero iff $f$ and $g$
have a common root $ (x,y) \neq (0,0)$. Back to
our business we assume $Z_0=(z_1,...,z_m) \in \mathbb{C}^m$ annihilates
the resultant $R$: that is $R_{\alpha \beta}(Z_0)=0$ for all
$\alpha, \beta$. Why this imply that the set
$f_i(Z_0, X,Y)$ has a common zero $\neq (0,0)$ in $X,Y$?

That all boils down to question:

Assume $g_i(X,Y)\in \mathbb{C}[X,Y], 1 \ge i \ge l$ are
homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$ and for *every* two sets
$(t_1,...,t_l), (s_1,...,s_l) \in \mathbb{C}^l$ the resultant
$R(\sum t_i g_i(X, Y), \sum s_i g_i(X,Y))$ is zero, i.e. $\sum t_i g_i(X, Y)$ and $ \sum s_i g_i(X,Y)$ have a common root.

Why the $g_i(X,Y)$ have a common zero $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$?

Comment: The resultant $R(f,g)$ is a polynomial in the coefficients of $f,g$. In your case, the coefficients involve the variables$t_i,s_i$ and we know that this polynomial (the resultant) vanishes at all values of $t_,s_i$. In other words, we have a polynomial that vanishes at every point. Do you see why this forces it to be zero?

Comment: BTW, I am a little confused as to what you mean by resultant of polynomials in 2 variables, are these homogeneous polynomials? I have only seen a definition of a resultant for polynomials in one variable.

Comment: Of course if $Z_0=(z_1,...,z_m) \in \mathbb{C}^m$ is a point with
where $R_{\alpha \beta}(Z_0)=0$ for all $\alpha, beta$, then
clearly $R= \sum R_{\alpha \beta}(Z_0) t^{\alpha} s^{\beta}$ 
is a zero polynomial. That's clear. But why this imply
that the $f_i(Z_0, X,Y)$ have a common zero? I not understand
the last conclusion. Could you elaborate it?

Comment: On your BTW question: See page 34 in Mumford's book. Conventionally, 
resultant $R$ is defined for two polynomials $f= \sum a_i X^{n-i},
f= \sum a_j X^{n-j}$ in one variable as you said. Mumford means
by $R(f,g)$ for two homogeneous polynomials $f(X,Y), g(X,Y) 
\in \mathbb{C}[X,Y]$ the resultant $R(f,g)$ of their localizastions
$f(X,1), g(X,1)$ in $Y$. Mumford explanes it more precisely in his book, 
but you are right, that seems to be non standard.

Comment: Resultant of two polynomials being 0 automatically implies that they have a common zero, no? I am not sure I understand your confusion.

Comment: What we concluded is that for every $Z_0=(z_1,...,z_m) \in \mathbb{C}^m$
with $R_{\alpha \beta}(Z_0)=0$ for every pair
$(t_1,...,t_l), (s_1,...,s_l) \in \mathbb{C}^l$ the two
polynomials $\sum t_i f_i(Z_0; X, Y)$ and $ \sum s_i f_i(Z_0; X,Y)$ have 
some common zeroes $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$. Why this imply that all $f_i(Z_0; X,Y),
1 \le i \le l$ have simultaneously a common zero? Recall the $l$ is fixed but arbitrary
number in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The problem is for example let $l=3$. By above the pair $f_1,f_2$ have pairwise common zeroes (because $R(f_1,f_2)=0$ as we showed) and the pair $f_2,f_3$ have also common zeroes (because $R(f_2,f_3)=0$). But in general this not imply that $f_1$ and $f_2$ and $f_3$ have common zeros. Set theoretically for example it's a basic fact that $A∩B≠∅$ and $B∩C≠∅$ in general not imply $A∩B∩C≠∅$. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Ok, I misread the question quite badly. I am writing an answer, lemme know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a case where we have 3 polynomials $f,g,h$ and suppose they don't have any common root. Your hypothesis in particular implies that for any $b,c \in \mathbb C$, $bg+ch$ and $f$ have a common root and this root has to be one of the roots of $f$.

But for every root $\alpha$ of $f$, the set of $b,c$ so that $bg(\alpha) + cg(\alpha) \neq 0$ is a Zariski open set $U_\alpha$ of $\mathbb C^3$ (since either $g(\alpha) \neq 0$ or $h(\alpha) \neq 0$).

If we take the intersection of these $U_\alpha$ over the roots $\alpha$ of $f$, we get something non empty and for any $b,c$ in this set $bg+ch$ does not vanish at *any* root of $f$.

Contradiction!

Comment: Thank you, probably the argument can be generalized from $3$ to arbitrary $m$.  
Assume we have our polynomials $f_1,...,f_m$ and let assume that
there exist a maximal $n <m$ with the property
such that wlog $f_1,...,f_n$ have common zero $\neq (0,0)$ but
$f_1,...,f_n, f_{n+1}$ don't have common zeroes. For every root $\alpha \in f_{n+1}$ the set $U_{\alpha} \subset C^m$ of
$(t_1,t_2,..., t_m)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n t_i f_i \neq 0$ is Zariski open and $f_{n+1} \in C[X,Y]$ has 
a finite number

Comment: of roots (since we consider only 'roots' 
in homogeneous sense; alternatively after localizing in $Y$ the
$f_{n+1}$ becomes polynomial in $C[X]$, so has finite number of roots)
thus the intersection $\bigcap_{\alpha} U_{\alpha}$ runs over a finite index $\alpha$ and is open and
not empty as $C^m$ irreducible. We obtain the same contradiction to
$R(\sum^n t_i f_i, f_{n+1}) =0$ as in your answer. Is this generalization proof correct?

Comment: Sounds right to me!